# the scala compiler cannot find the correct generic function parameter

Tags: scala, generics

I have scala code as following

```
object Main extends App {
   def getFun[T, U](x: Array[T] => U, p: Array[T]): U = { x(p) }
   def getFun2(x: Array[Int] => Double, p: Array[Int]): Double = { x(p) }

   val arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
   println(getFun((x: Array[Int]) => x.sum, arr))
   // println(getFun(_.sum, arr))  // error, why!
   // println(getFun(x = _.sum, arr))  // error, why!
   println(getFun2(_.sum.toDouble, p = arr))
}
```

Why **getFun** cannot be used as simple as **getFun2**.
I think use the "x = _.sum", the scala compiler can find the correct type, but it seems that it failed.

Can any body explain the reason of the error.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getFun` uses type variables whereas `getFun2` uses explicit types.

So, for `getFun2`, the compiler knows that it is calling the `sum` function on an `Array[Int]`. It knows how to sum up Integers, things work.

For `getFun` the compiler only knows that there is an array of *something* (`T` stands for *some type*). It does not how to sum up *something*, we have to help the compiler here and tell it what `T` is. One possibility is what you did in the first line, specifying the array type in the function lambda. Another would be to pass along type parameter values like this:

```
println(getFun[Int,Double](_.sum, arr))
```